# How to make XCode 6 show only relevant code completions

Tags: xcode, swift, xcode6

In XCode 6, using Swift; lets say I'm creating an instance of some object:

```
let sessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration()
```

**Is there a way to tell XCode 6 code completion to only include methods/properties that is actually defined on the NSURLSessionConfiguration class or it's super classes?**

Using the object defined above XCode code completion suggests that I use methods like:

```
sessionConfiguration.accessibilityActionDescription(action: String)
sessionConfiguration.animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation!)
```

But I can't see that those methods would be relevant for this class.

This seems like odd behavior in the new Swift programming paradigm obsessed with code safety.

Answer (score 0):

```
extension NSObject {

/* Called when the animation begins its active duration. */

func animationDidStart(anim: CAAnimation!)

/* Called when the animation either completes its active duration or
 * is removed from the object it is attached to (i.e. the layer). 'flag'
 * is true if the animation reached the end of its active duration
 * without being removed. */

func animationDidStop(anim: CAAnimation!, finished flag: Bool)
}


extension NSObject {

/*
 Implement accessibilityActivate on an element in order to handle the default action.
 For example, if a native control requires a swipe gesture, you may implement this method so that a
 VoiceOver user will perform a double-tap to activate the item.
 If your implementation successfully handles activate, return YES, otherwise return NO.
 default == NO
 */
@availability(iOS, introduced=7.0)
func accessibilityActivate() -> Bool

...}
```

The two methods are Extension of NSObject declare in **CAAnimation** and **UIAccessibility**

Comment: That explains why they are showing as auto completions. And I guess that we can't do anything about it. Why Apple extends NSObject with these features is strange. It adds a lot of distraction in my opinion. Thanks for responding though!

Answer (score 0):

Based on bumaociyuan's answer. The answer to my original question is:

No.

XCode autocompletion shows every method in the class hierarchy. Some methods are added to the class through inheritance, some by extensions.